# Transferring Data Between Client and Server and Dynamically Flush

Tags: java, c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I've been playing around with transferring data between a test client (written in Java) and a server (written in C#/.NET).

I tried TCP clients and servers, but there has been and current is a problem flushing the stream. I realize flush doesn't always flush the stream, so I'm wondering if there is any way to flush/send a stream without .flush() or in a more reliable way?

Currently, the important part of the client looks like this (message is a string, serverSocket is a Socket object):

```
OutputStream output = serverSocket.getOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
int length = buffer.length;

output.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(length).array());
output.write(buffer);
output.flush();
```

and the server looks like this:

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream ();

byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];
int read = stream.Read (sizeBuffer, 0, 4);

int size = BitConverter.ToInt32 (sizeBuffer, 0);
Databaser.log ("recieved byte message denoting size: " + size);

byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[size];
read = stream.Read (messageBuffer, 0, size);

string result = BitConverter.ToString (messageBuffer);
Databaser.log ("\tmessage is as follows: '" + result + "'");
```

Where, if it's not evident from the code, the client sends 4 bytes, which are combined into a 32 bit integer which is the length of the message. Then I read in the message based on that length and have build in converters translate it into a string.

As I said, I'm wondering how to flush the connection? I know this code isn't perfect, but I can change it back to when I used TCP and UTF exclusive string messaging over the network, but either way, the connection doesn't send anything from the client until the client shuts down or closes the connection.

Comment: It's not evident from any of this what your actual problem is. 'Flush doesn't always flush the stream' is certainly not correct, and neither is the claim that nothing gets sent until you close the connection. You're making a number of basic programming errors here, such as ignoring the count returned by read(), any of which would be sufficient to cause problems. I would investigate using the facilities of DataInoutStream, notably readInt() and readFully().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the byte order. I have an application which send from a tablet (java) to a C# application (Windows Intel), I used similar to what you've done, except in the following

```
ByteBuffer iLength = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
iLength.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
iLength.putInt(length);
output.write(iLength.array(), 0, 4);
output.write(buffer);
output.flush();
```

Java uses BIG-ENDIAN and Intel uses LITTLE-ENDIAN bytes order.

Comment: The BIG-ENDIAN and LITTLE-ENDIAN does seem to make a difference, and fixed my code, thank you, I was not aware of this. I'm self teaching these things so I don't know half of the important context here, thanks again.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel You're welcome. Keep in mind, though; that what I've coded is only when sending to an Intel machine, or LITTLE-ENDIAN ones.  If the server happens to be a BIG-ENDIAN machine then you got the some problem back again. But now you know the fact of bytes order so you are aware of it.